When building a Xamarin.iOS app, why is there a Distribution provisioning profile match for a Developer Signing Identity?
I have a project file where the Debug|iPhoneSimulator configuration has this:
<CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
<CodesignProvision>Automatic</CodesignProvision>

MSBuild is printing this when building that configuration:
...
[MSBuild] PrepareForBuild:
[MSBuild]   Creating directory "bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/".
[MSBuild]   Creating directory "obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/".
...
[MSBuild] _DetectSigningIdentity:
[MSBuild]   Multiple provisioning profiles match the bundle identifier; using the first match.
[MSBuild]           
[MSBuild]     1. Provisioning Profile: "Dev: com.test.*" (<guid>)
[MSBuild]     2. Provisioning Profile: "Dev: *" (<guid>)
[MSBuild]     3. Provisioning Profile: "Ad Hoc Dist: com.test.*" (<guid>)
...

I understand why the first 2 provisioning profiles could match because they are both Development provisioning profiles that have a wildcard overlap.
However, I don't understand why the Ad Hoc profile is a match since it uses a Distribution cert, and is an Ad Hoc profile. I'm looking for info on why this is happening and/or recommendations on how to correct this.
